# How to instantiate Presenter in AppWidgetProvider?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I am trying to use a presenter with AppWidgetProvider.

I have an instance variable as following

`private latelinit var presenter: Presenter`

Then inside `onEnabled`, I set the presenter. And then inside `onUpdate`, I am using the presenter.

```
    override fun onEnabled(context: Context?) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Inside onEnabled")
        setPresenter(Presenter(this))
        super.onEnabled(context)
    }
    
    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Inside onUpdate")
        presenter!!.onUpdate(context, appWidgetIds)
    }

    override fun setPresenter(presenter: Presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Inside onSetPresenter Presenter set")
    }
```

As per logs, `onEnabled` is called prior to `onUpdate` which is what I expect. However, when I use presenter inside `onUpdate`, it complains of Presenter not being initialized.

What is the right way to set presenter inside an AppWidgetProvider?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the right way to set presenter inside an AppWidgetProvider?

You would not "set" it. At most, you would create an instance in `onUpdate()` and use it.

An `AppWidgetProvider` is a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`. An instance of your `AppWidgetProvider` will be used for a single callback, then discarded. Storing data in properties of the `AppWidgetProvider`, such as your presenter, is useless.

Comment: Interesting. So if I have to use presenter with `AppWidgetProvider`, do I have to instantiate a new presenter everytime `onUpdate` is called? I want to use a presenter for better code organization. Does this also mean static variables is a strict no no and using Shared Preferences for any kind of caching is the right approach when dealing with AppWidgetProviders. Thanks, Mark! Legend :D

Comment: @suhas_sm: "So if I have to use presenter with AppWidgetProvider, do I have to instantiate a new presenter everytime onUpdate is called?" -- yes. "Does this also mean static variables is a strict no no" -- using static variables is generally only used for caches. In particular, in this case, there is no guarantee that it will be the same process between two subsequent calls of callbacks on your `AppWidgetProvider`. "using Shared Preferences for any kind of caching is the right approach" -- if you need to save data, persistence of some form will be required.